# Compare differences in Multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, comparison

I have a rather ugly query, and the results from the query are then post-processed using php which turns each row into it's own multidimensional array.

I want to refactor the query but need to make sure I do not change what it returns in any way.

So What I want to do is copy the original query and call that, store the results.
then run the function again with my new query.

Loop over the two arrays of results and compare them for any differences what so ever (keys, values, missing entries, type differences etc).

What is the easiest way to do this?

Essentially I know how to call the two queries etc,

I guess my real question is, at the end once I have my two arrays of the results how do I go through and compare them.

What I would love to end up with is a side by side "print_r" type output with a red line or similar going across highlighting any differences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you can use [array_uintersect_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect-assoc.php) like this.

```
// First get intersecting values
$intersect = array_uintersect_assoc($expected, $results, "checkStructure");
print_r($intersect);

//Then print results that are in intersecting set (e.g. structure of $expected, value  of $results
print_r(array_uintersect_assoc($results, $intersect, "checkStructure"));

function checkStructure($x, $y) {
   if (!is_array($x) && !is_array($y)) {
      return 0;
   }
   if (is_array($x) && is_array($y)) {
       if (count($x) == count($y)) {
           foreach ($x as $key => $value) {
               if(array_key_exists($key,$y)) {
                   $x = checkStructure($value, $y[$key]);
                   if ($x != 0) return -1;
               } else {
                   return -1;
               }
           }
       }
   } else {
       return -1;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

If still not, take help of [array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) 
and [array_diff_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php). Or try following code.

```
function multidimensional_array_diff($a1,$a2) 
{ 
   $r = array(); 
   foreach ($a2 as $key => $second) 
   { 
      foreach ($a1 as $key => $first) 
      { 
         if (isset($a2[$key])) 
         { 
            foreach ($first as $first_value) 
            { 
               foreach ($second as $second_value) 
               { 
                   if ($first_value == $second_value) 
                   { 
                      $true = true; 
                      break;    
                   }    
               } 
               if (!isset($true)) 
               { 
                   $r[$key][] = $first_value; 
               } 
               unset($true); 
            } 
         } 
         else 
         { 
            $r[$key] = $first; 
         } 
      } 
   } 
   return $r; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just make a `VIEW` that turns an ugly query into something you can just `SELECT` against? What you're talking about is making a materialized view, something that MySQL doesn't handle as well as other database platforms.

Comment: This *may* answer how to do the refactoring in SQL, but it does not address how to be certain the end result is the same.

Comment: Oh, well, if you want to compare the results of two queries you could use either a `TEMPORARY TABLE` where you can query `WHERE result_a != result_b` given A and B are populated with your results. In a pinch you can just build these with `INSERT INTO temp_table (SELECT ...)` and then `INSERT IGNORE INTO temp_table (SELECT ...) ON DUPLICATE KEY SET ...` but it gets kind of messy. Two different queries combined in the application layer isn't a terrible idea compared with that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not write the results of each query out to a text files then compare the two text files with the `diff` command?

Comment: That's essentially what I am doing at the moment, but I was just hoping there was a way to "diff" it in php ;) as that would be somewhat faster (I have about 50 queries I need to go over)

Comment: have you looked at php's array_diff()?

Comment: Yeah, it can give me an array of the differences, but I want to be able to do a print_r type output with a side by side view of the entire result set.